# JSF + Spring + JPA + Hibernate: keep entitymanager alive when rendering view?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsf, jpa

Totally new to Spring & Java development but working on a project for a class with some experienced developers.  I believe we're using Spring MVC as our web layer(but I'm a C# guy so I may be mistaken in that regard).  We have a view that gets an object with lazily loaded properties -- pretty straightforward stuff.  Yet when I call one of these properties within a JSF view, I get this error:

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxxxxxxx, 
  no session or session was closed
```

which makes me think that the hibernate session is being closed much too early.  Is there a way to have one entitymanager that stays alive for the duration of the request, including after the model is sent to the view for rendering?

Comment: Apart from the particular problem, why don't you just short this with those experienced developers? They're certainly eager to explain you the problem and the solution. You're in fact also all supposed to work together and learn from each other.

Comment: Only one has extensive hibernate experience.  He insists that you have to burn an eager-load query to get anything additional to load.  I think that's insane, especially since we're in an early phase of development and don't know which relationship if any needs to be optimized with an eager load.  My .NET experience tells me that he may be locked into one way of doing things.

Comment: well, if he doesn't state any specific reasons to eagerly load the data, then he just doesn't have good hibernate experience. You are entirely correct that lazy-loading is achievable and preferred in many cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring provides the [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) and [OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html). They are the `EntityManager` version of the [OpenSessionInView (OSIV) paradigm](https://www.hibernate.org/43.html)

Comment: Works like a charm.  Now to convince my compatriots that it's worth doing.